# Assigning complex values to gsl matrix

Tags: c, linear-algebra, gsl

I am trying to write a simple program to diagonalize a complex (hermitian) Hamiltonian matrix, using the GNU Scientific Library. I have scoured the documentation and the internet, but I simply cannot find the procedure to assign complex values to a gsl_matrix.

Would it be something as simple as this:

```
gsl_complex Hij = gsl_complex_rect(double x, double y)

gsl_matrix_set(H, i, j, Hij)
```

This assumes that gsl_matrix_set detects complex numbers (versus real numbers) and automatically handles the memory allocation.

Or, would it be something like this:

```
gsl_matrix_set(H, i, j, x)
gsl_matrix_set(H, i, j+1, y)
```

assuming that complex numbers are stored as pair of numbers in memory, as is the convention elsewhere. But, then how would the eigensystem routines be able to make the distinction? I am really lost on this simple thing.

How do you assign complex numbers to a gsl_matrix?

Comment: you probably will want to take a look at [gsl_matrix_complex](https://fossies.org/dox/gsl-2.1/structgsl__matrix__complex.html)

Comment: Oh, okay. That's actually pretty simple. It's odd that they don't mention gsl_matrix_complex in the documentation, except as arguments to other functions.

Answer (score 0):

use `gsl_matrix_complex_set(gsl_matrix_complex H, size_t n, size_t m, gsl_complex z);`, example setting all entries in the matrix to $n+im$:

```
#include<complex.h>//Required for better complex notation (a+I*b)
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_complex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main()
{
    int N =5;
    int M =6;
    gsl_matrix_complex* H = gsl_matrix_complex_alloc (N, M);
    gsl_matrix_complex_set_zero(H);//From my testing, the matrix is usually 0 when it is created, but the documentation does not GUARANTEE this
    //You could also use:
    //gsl_matrix_complex_set_all(H, 0+0*I);//c complex notation! Requires that <complex.h> was included prior to <gsl_complex.h>!!!

    //Loop through all our states and calculate all matrix elements
    for (int n = 0; n < N;++n)
        for (int m = 0; m < M;++m)
        {
            gsl_complex z= (n+I*m);//Likely reall the result of <i | H | j> calculation, in practice we know the Hamiltonian is hermitian, so we could skip half the calculations, but lets just set this to i+I j
            gsl_matrix_complex_set(H, n, m, z);
        }

    //Lets just print the result, to see that this worked
    for (int n = 0; n < N;++n)
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < M;++m)
        {
            gsl_complex z=gsl_matrix_complex_get(H, n, m);
            printf("%f+i %f ",GSL_REAL(z),GSL_IMAG(z));
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
    gsl_matrix_complex_free(H);
    return 0;
}
```

I know this question is old, but it still comes up in search results.